# How to stop vscode from removing indent when closing curly braces

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, formatting, indentation, curly-braces

hope you guys can help me out, vscode is removing the indentation when I close curly braces and this is annyoing me, here is a gif of what's happenning

[vscode removing indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah6jM.gif)

Comment: I use prettier and have the same problem but as soon as I save it'll format it correcty.

Answer (score 1):

Change **Auto Indent** in your settings (Text editor) to **keep** from **full**. (see screenshot below)

[image: Auto Indent settings]

Note: It can affect something another, but it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your VS code doesn't know about JSX in your JS files.
Try to change your user settings or workspace settings as below:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```

Note: You might need to restart VSCode.

Comment: tried it, but still removing indent :c thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found another solution. Please, check below.