# VS Code removes indentation when typing close brace in PHP files

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, auto-indent

When I type a closing curly brace on an indented line, the indentation of that line and the entire block it closes is reduced to zero.

[image: Animation showing the problem]

The answer offered at [How to stop vscode from removing indent when closing curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63199416/how-to-stop-vscode-from-removing-indent-when-closing-curly-braces) is to set 'auto indent' to 'keep' but I've tried all the 'autoindent' options with no luck.

Someone suggested installing 'PHP Intelliphense' plugin, this did not change the behaviour.  I uninstalled it again.

Disabling the 'PHP' 'All-in-One PHP support' extension from DEVSENSE did not help.

Disabling the 'PHP Docblocker' extension did not help.

Disabling the 'PHP cs fixer' extension did not help.

At this point I have no PHP extensions enabled, still having the problem.

I read at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40235 that c# developers had a similar problem, so I disabled the `C#` extension, also did not change the behaviour.

Similar behaviour with HTML in a PHP file, but in that case only the line where the closing `>` is typed is unindented, the entire block is not.  HTML in a file considered html (with a `.html` extension, say) is not affected, so this still seems related to the PHP language features.

[image: Animation of HTML file exhibiting similar behaviour]

Since I've tried the different 'auto indent' options with no luck, what else can I try?

I'm using VS Code 1.82.2 on Fedora Linux 38.

I'm trying the suggestions from @starball (thanks!)

EDIT 2: It seems to have been the `php cs fixer` extension from `junstyle`.  Disabling it does prompt for an editor restart, so I'm not sure why I missed this earlier.  Enabling it does not prompt for a restart, but immediately brings in the indentation problem.  I installed it to get PSR-12 formatting support, which does not seem well supported anywhere I've looked.

[image: Animation of php-cs-fixer breaking things]

Comment: 3) Does this happen if you run with default settings? (Ex. create a new and empty [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)) 4) What if you close the opening `<?php`?

Comment: Thanks @starball - to my great annoyance, while writing the above post I upgraded the `code` package to the latest, `1.83.0`, and the problem seems to have stopped happening. It may be that a full restart (and not just the 'restart' button when disabling extensions) tickled something, or the new `vscode` version may have different behaviour.. I'll see if I can make it happen again.

Comment: hold on. before I write up an answer, are you 100% sure of this? would you mind doing a sanity check with enabling just that extension and nothing else, checking, and then disabling all extensions and checking again? because it would seem weird to me for that extension to cause this behaviour... because [according to its docs](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer#php-cs-fixer-for-visual-studio-code), all it does is contribute a command

Comment: @starball this is very weird. A fresh Profile does not have the problem, installing php-cs-fixer does reinstate the problem, so it seems connected. A fresh project with `composer require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer` brings latest `PHP CS Fixer 3.34.1` into `vendor`, config extension to use this binary and running 'Fix this file' makes no changes, but typing closing brace has the problem. So the php-cs-fixer binary is making no changes to the file. What's causing the problem?

Comment: @starball https://nickfenwick.com/Peek-2023-10-06-14-07.gif video of fresh profile attempt, fresh php-cs-fixer install, fresh extension add & config.

Comment: Incidentally, running `php-cs-fixer` on the command line with the incorrect indentation in the `test.php` file fixes the indentation perfectly, undoing the zero indentation caused when typing the `}`, so I don't believe it's the binary causing the problem, it seems to be something either in VS Code or the php-cs-fixer extension that's screwing it up.  Also, using the VS Code command "fix this file" to run the binary also fixes the indentation.  I don't know enough about extensions to begin to debug it.

Comment: FYI I have opened an Issue at https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer/issues/208 as this seems more connected to the extension than a core VS Code problem and may be better debugged by people familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour was found to be caused by the [`junstyle.php-cs-fixer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer) extension. It's quite strange because according to the extension's docs, it just contributes a command... Anyhow, there are now issue tickets tracking the behaviour:

- [Block loses indentation when close brace is typed
  #208](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer/issues/208)
- [Auto-indent issue #209](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer/issues/209)

I suggest that you give those issue tickets a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

When you encounter undesirable behaviours, it's often helpful to figure out if an extension is causing them. To do that, ask yourself the following: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.